# Optimize Performance for creating views at runtime

Tags: android, performance, programmatically-created

I'm confronted with the Problem of slow Performance...

Just take a case:

```
RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myrlLayout);
//Adding now 100 Buttons with 100 TextViews below each Button(just a example)
for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setId(i+1); //Should be a positive integer
    //set LayoutParams for Button
    RelativeLayout.Layoutparams btn_layoutparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams....
    ....
    myLayout.addView(btn, btn_layoutparams);
    TextView mytv = new TextView(this);
    mytv.setid(101+i);
    //set LayoutParams for Button with referenced to the Button(because the Textview Needs to be
    of Button)
    ....
    myLayout.addView(mytv, tv-layoutparams);
}
```

Regarding to the high amount of Views programmatically created, my app starts really slow...
I think it's not because of creating a new View, but because of setting the LayoutParamters each time for the view. I can't find a Workaround because my LayoutParams for the TextView for example Need to reference to the button created before. Due to that i'm not really able to create a XML-layout-file or XML-style-file because i can't reference the tv's layoutparameters anchor in the XML-file to the button which does not exist at the Moment. At least i didn't find a way. I hope somebody got an idea how to appreciable improve the Performance when creating such a amount of views at runtime. Every advise is welcome.

**Update regarding answere from rom4ek**

The Problem is, that i Need to calculate how much views can i add per row before the Screen-width is fully used. That means i Need second LayoutParams to add the next Button below the first Button from the first row. And i also Need to reference to the img-Button added before in the LayoutParams.. so it's not possible to reference LayoutParams to a Button which doesn't exist before the for-loop.Maybe i completely miss something.. Do you have an idea/solution? Thank you for your respond.

Comment: found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the same `LayoutParams`, what if you move `RelativeLayout.Layoutparams btn_layoutparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams....` before the cycle? So you will initialize it one time, and then no need to create new LayoutParams every step.